# AngularJS check if function exists in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive with the following scope:

```js
scope: {
  copyObject: '&',
  deleteObject: '&'
}
```

Now, I have a corresponding button in my template which looks like this:

```html
 <button ng-click="copyObject()">Copy</button>
```

However, I would like to hide the button if there's no function applied to `copy-object`, for example:

```
<!-- Should show the copy button -->
<my-directive copy-object="copyObject()"></my-directive>

<!-- Should not show the copy button -->
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

So I applied the following to my template:

```html
<button ng-click="copyObject()" ng-if="copyObject">Copy</button>
```

But this does not seem to work, if I check the directives real isolated scope, I notice that, even when the attribute is not entered, the function still exists, so the button is always visible.

Is it possible to detect if a function is bound to the `copyObject()` or not? And is it a good practice to do so? I'm not sure if the directive should be aware of the bound function or is this some kind of scope access violation?

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/azchpo5q/ (the second button should not be visible because there is no action bound to it).

Comment: The clicking is not the problem (that already works with brackets), but I would like to hide the button if no function is bound to it. I added a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azchpo5q/ The second button should not be visible as it has no `copy-object` attribute.

Comment: I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935099/how-to-check-if-a-method-argument-of-a-directive-is-specified-in-angularjs (I also voted to close as a duplicate)

Comment: Thx g00glen00b, your answer solved my problem!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function in `ng-if` to determine if the function is defined.

```
<button ng-click="copyObject()" ng-if="doShowCopy()">Copy</button>
```

Then define this method:

```
 $scope.doShowCopy = function() {
     return (typeof $scope.copyObject == 'function');
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that `typeof $scope.copyObject` is **always** a function, because this is a wrapper function not direct function that comes from outer scope.

Comment: Sure? I am guessing it might be defined in the scope, but not as a function!!

Comment: It is defined as a function yes, if I use `directive.isolateScope().copyObject` it returns a function. I solved it thanks to another question though, by using the `attrs` from the `link()` function. I marked it as a duplicate.

Comment: Absolutely sure. This function which basically tries to evaluate a function in parent scope.

Comment: So, is it defined as a function for any type of attribute? I mean how is the angularjs assuming that to be a function? Am just curious!!

Comment: @Prasad It assumes that because the function is bound as `&`. So AngularJS knows that it should be a function and it returns a wrapper, like @dfsq mentioned. You can see it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azchpo5q/2/

Comment: Ya, got it! It's defined as a function because it's one-way binding, but not because you are binding a function to it. It's always defined as a function (whether you are binding a function or a string) with a closure inside if it's one way binding!