# Default controllerAs for the Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, default, unspecified-behavior

What is the default for `controllerAs` for the Angular directive definition if it is not specified?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a method argument of a directive is specified in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935099/how-to-check-if-a-method-argument-of-a-directive-is-specified-in-angularjs)

Comment: @PaulSweatte What is the default then? :)

Comment: [Unit tests](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/compileSpec.js) describe the behaviour as such: `it('should throw noident when missing controller identifier'` and `it('should throw noident when missing controllerAs directive property'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit tests describe the default behaviour of `controllerAs` in the directive definition object(ddo) as such:

```
it('should throw noident when missing controller identifier')

it('should throw noident when missing controllerAs directive property')
```

**References**

- [AngularJS Source: compileSpec.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/compileSpec.js)
- [AngularJS: Controller as ... and closures](http://www.filipesperandio.com/blog/2014/06/10/angularjs-controller-as-dot-dot-dot/)

Comment: Interesting, I don't recall seeing any uncaught `noident`. Perhaps it was caught somewhere and handled discreetly?