# In AngularJS, how to determine if an attribute is provided to a component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I have an AngularJS 1.5 component that takes an optional callback function as an attribute binding. I would like to determine whether that attribute is included.

```
<silly-button></silly-button> <!-- Don't Click Me! -->
<silly-button on-silly-click="handleClick()"></silly-button> <!-- Click Me! -->
```

Given the trivial example below, how can I implement the the `onClickIsNotProvided()` function?

```
angular
  .module('example')
  .component('sillyButton')
  .bindings({
    onSillyClick: '&'
  })
  .controller(['$scope', ($scope) => {
    $scope.onClickIsNotProvided = () => {
      // this.onSillyClick is always defined, so return value is always false :(
      return !this.onSillyClick;
    };
  }])
  .template(`
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.onSillyClick()">
      <span ng-if="onClickIsNotProvided()">Don't</span>
      Click Me!
    </button>
  `);
```

Comment: Simply by using a different attribute name than the standard https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp one ?

Comment: I've changed the attribute name in my dumbed down example to `on-silly-click` to avoid confusion with standard attributes.

Comment: maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33935950/445600

Comment: @starcorn Good idea! Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney the optional parameter `?` is a standard for angular bindings. By the way I suggest you to provide also another check through `angular.isFunction` to be sure that the parameter that has been passed is really a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `&?` same as `=?`, `@?` to mark whether that parameter is optional or not.

Some reference can be found in [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). Although it does not specifically talk about optional function bindings.

Comment: Thanks. I sent a PR to mention the feature in the place where I would expect to find it in the docs. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/16017

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the function that you would have to add:

```
function onClickIsNotProvided(item) {

    var elementAttributeValue = item.attributes['on-silly-click'].value;
    if (!elementAttributeValue) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
}
```

This would go into the same place as your other angular for the controller.

Comment: In the above, you would be passing in the element you're trying to check.